# getting product URL by ID

Tags: product, url

is it possible to quickly get a products URL from it's id?  We're having an issue where the product URLs of configured (simple child) products are overlapping.  By this I mean when 2+ configurations (simple children) of a configurable product are added to the cart the URLs always divert to the first option

Comment: A sidenote: Magento will create a URL for not visible simple products of configurables: http://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 7):

You can get product url by loading catalog product model object  using product id

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load($id);

$productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: This is returning a url like this:
 http://formodulecheck.dev/index.php/catalog/product/view/  , but I need to get a url like: C:\wamp64\www\formodulecheck.dev\media\catalog\product\p\r\product.jpg . Could you please tell @Marius how can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$productId` with your product ID below. You can also specify different store (or store ID will also work) in the 3rd argument.

```
$urlKey = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
  ->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore());
$productUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl() . $urlKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).$_product->getUrlKey();
```